# detecting when a UISlider finishes Xcode

Tags: uiimageview, xcode6, uislider

I have a UISlider that makes a UIImageView move from side to side by setting the x value in CGRectMake the UISlider.value.  I want to detect when the slider stops so I can have another action happen.  How would I go about detecting when the UISlider stops and then write an if statement to do something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954498/in-uikit-how-to-detect-when-a-uislider-has-stopped-moving-but-has-not-been-rele

Answer (score 0):

I found out that all I needed to do was add

```
[zoomSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(stopSlider)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

inside the IBACTION for my slider and then add

```
-(void) stopSlider;{

  with whatever code I wanted to happen when I stop touching the slider here
}
```